# How to detect when Zebra PS20 personal shopper is removed from cradle

Tags: javascript, dom-events, barcode-scanner, polling, zebra-scanners

How to discover when Zebra PS20J personal shopper is taken from smart cradle when cradle is unlocked?

Zebra Enterprise Browser 2 is used in Android 8.

I tried in javascript in browser

```js
const unlockparam = {
  "ledOnDuration": 1000,
  "ledOffDuration": 1000,
  "timeout": 10,
  "smoothingEffect": true
};

EB.SmartCradle.unlockEx(unlockparam, function () {
  console.write('Device is taken from Cradle');
});
```

But unlock callback fires immediately after unlocking, not after device is taken.

How to detect device detach from cradle? I tried to poll cradle wallId property using:

```js
EB.SmartCradle.getProperty("wallId") !== 0
```

But `wallId` returns value even after PS20 is removed from cradle.
Haven't found any description about it in Zebra SmartCradle API reference in https://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/latest/api/smartcradle/

Getting device from cradle stops charging. Is it possible/reasonable to check charging state to dedect removal using API like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API?

I posted this also in Zebra developers forum in https://developer.zebra.com/content/how-dedect-when-ps20j-removed-cradle but havent got response.